# Simple Sum & Group

Tags: sql

I have a table that has 2 simple fields: RoomNumber & RoomEarned

I would like to group the rooms together that have multiple RoomEarned Values and combine their sum. Basically adding the value together inline.

basically making this table..

RoomNumber | RoomEarned
1 |     13.23
2 |     23.79
3 |     50.75
4 |     32.90
10 |    11.31
11 |    31.83
**12 |     13.92

12 |    18.82**

13 |    41.87
14 |    87.74
15 |    100.83

into this...

RoomNumber | RoomEarned
1 |     13.23
2 |     23.79
3 |     50.75
4 |     32.90
10 |    11.31
11 |    31.83
**12 |     32.74**

13 |    41.87
14 |    87.74
15 |    100.83

Obviously its a grouping function, but to my abilities.. I fall terribly short.

any ideas?

Comment: Really? second link https://www.google.com.au/#fp=a0ea4b90eb40f363&q=sql+sum+group+by

Answer (score 5):

```
select RoomNumber, SUM(RoomEarned) from MyTable group by RoomNumber
```